# How to get key/value data from PushNotification in PhoneGap Build

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I'm using the Push plugin in PhoneGap Build.  I am able to send as well as receive push notifications to my device.  I'm sending the notification + additional data (specifically which page to load) using the node-gcm library to registered devices.  Here's the code on my node.js server:

```
var gcm = require('node-gcm');
var message = new gcm.Message();

//API Server Key
var sender = new gcm.Sender('GCM API SERVER/BROWSER KEY');
var registrationIds = [];

// Value the payload data to send...
message.addData('message','Hello from Portland, OR!');
message.addData('title','My Push Notification');
message.addData('msgcnt','3'); 
message.addData('soundname','beep.wav'); 
message.addDataWithKeyValue('pageid','1234566788');  //THIS IS THE ADDITIONAL DATA I'D
// ... ID LIKE TO SEND TO MY PHONEGAP BUILD APP AND INTERPRET
message.timeToLive = 3;// Duration in seconds to hold and retry to deliver the message in GCM before timing out. Default 4 weeks if not specified

// At least one reg id required
registrationIds.push('REGISTRATION ID');

/**
 * Parameters: message-literal, registrationIds-array, No. of retries, callback-function
 */
sender.send(message, registrationIds, 4, function (result) {
    console.log("hello" + result);
});
```

Now that I believe I have sent the additional page data, I'd like to know how I can GET the data from the notification itself inside of my PhoneGap build application.

I'm also using jquery mobile to manage the different html pages (which basically makes each page a separate div inside of one html document) and could use feedback on how to load the notified page with this in mind.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks so much!

-- 24x7

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value of key/pairs of notification in phonegap as follows:
The message text can be retrieved with: **e.message**
All other key/value pairs can be retrieved with: **e.payload.key**

For example if you want get the title of the notification(in above) then you will get it in "e.payload.title".
After getting the value you can put conditional statemnets depending upon the value to go to different pages/divs.